# Duplicate decimal marker (siunitx)

Tags: siunitx

My table has numbers in a same cell as follows: 23,3 (3,5). When I try to align decimals with siunitx, it gives me the following message:

Duplicate decimal marker token ',' in input.

Where lies the error?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment = center, input-symbols=(), output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}[c]{l
S[table-format=3.1]
S[table-format=3.1]
S[table-format=1.3]}


\caption{my-caption). \label{long-representativity}}\\

\toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{LTF\textsuperscript{a} at 3 years (n = 129)}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Still followed at 3 years (n = 246)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{p-value}}\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{l}{Sociodemographics}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \midrule
                                                                                                                                                       \\
Age, mean (s.d)                                            & 23,3 (3,5)              & 23,3 (3,6)                        & 0,849   \\
```

Answer (score 5):

`siunitx` will scan for a decimal marker which is the comma.  You cannot have two commas in one entry unless you enclose one of them in a group.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment = center, input-symbols=(), output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{l
      S[table-format=3.1]
      S[table-format=3.1]
      S[table-format=1.3]}
    \caption{my-caption). \label{long-representativity}}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{{}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{{LTF\textsuperscript{a} at 3 years (n = 129)}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Still followed at 3 years (n = 246)}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{{p-value}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Sociodemographics} \\
    \midrule
    \\
    Age, mean (s.d) & 23,3 {(3,5)} & 23,3 {(3,6)} & 0,849 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]